# String initialization and printing

Tags: c++, string

Table 3.1 under article 3.2.1 in [C++ Primer, Fifth edition](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Lippman-C-Primer-5th-Edition/PGM270560.html) states:

> `string s3("value")`  ->  s3 is a copy of the string literal, not
>   including the null.

My interpretation of this is - when we initialize a string like `string s1("value");`, the variable `s1` contains a copy of the string `value` *without* the `NUL` character at the end.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(void)
{
        string s1("value");

        cout << s1 << endl;   // prints - value
}
```

So, does this program invoke UB as `s1` does not have a `NUL` terminator and we are printing the string?

I am asking this because, in C, trying to print a c-string without a `NUL` terminator produces UB. Is it not mandatory for strings in C++ to end with a `NUL`?

What am I missing here?

Comment: *"Is it not mandatory for strings in C++ to end with a NUL?"* That's right. `std::string` isn't like C-style strings, it doesn't need null terminators. You can even have NUL in the strings.

Comment: But note that, if you want to assign a c-string to an `std::string` using a single pointer to it, the c-string *does* need to have a null terminator. Otherwise, it isn't a c-string. But the `std::string` isn't required to store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it not mandatory for strings in C++ to end with a NUL?

Depends on what you mean by "strings".  `std::string` do not end in a nul character because the length is known/stored.  C-style strings (aka `char*` arrays) returned by `std::string::c_str()` must end a nul character because the length is unknown/not stored.

Answer (score 2):

> So, does this program invoke UB as s1 does not have a NUL terminator and we are printing the string?

No.  `std::string` provides an overload of `operator <<` that "does the right thing".  You don't have to worry about it.

> I am asking this because trying to print a c-string without a NUL terminator produces UB. Is it not mandatory for strings in C++ to end with a NUL?

That will depend on which version of the standard you are using C++98/03 doesn't require there to be a null terminator at the end of the string but `c_str` basically forces you to do so.  C++11 and above though do guarantee that there is a null terminator at the end of the string data.

Do note that the terminating null character is still not needed as `std::string`'s `operator <<` could look like

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < member_variable_size; ++i)
    std::cout << member_variable_data[i]
```

so it would work regardless if there was one or not.  In fact it pretty much has to do this since `std::string` is allowed to have embedded nulls in it and it will string print correctly like how

```
int main() 
{
    std::string foo("h\0ell\0o", 7);
    std::cout << foo;
}
```

prints

```
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here?

[This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) operator overload that takes a `std::string` as the second argument. So `std::cout << s1` doesn't print a c-string without a null terminator, you are invoking a function `operator <<` and pass `s1` to it.

> So, does this program invoke UB as `s1` does not have a NUL terminator and we are printing the string?

In general, you can rely upon the competence of the developers behind the standard library in use, i.e., it seems safe to me to use this overloaded operator :)